# Should I upvote for having the same problem

Tags: discussion, questions, up-votes

Often I find a google search leads me back here.

When I find these questions I tend to upvote them as they were helpful to me, they have a asked and got an answer to the problem I was facing.

Obviously I upvote the answer that had the solution to my problem and any others that were helpful but I also tend to upvote the question as well. If it was not op I would not have the answers that were so helpful but is this a good reason to upvote questions if its not that good a question ?

Comment: It's a perfectly good reason to up-vote.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, sounds reasonable, but you can do better: if the question isn't very good, *make it better*!

Edit it, clean it up in any way you see fit, possibly even add a phrase or two to make it more searchable (if you had a bit of trouble locating it – as long as you don't change the meaning of the question of course).

Once you've done that, not only is SO better off with a nicer question, but people having the same problem will find their solution even faster. Win for everyone.

Comment: I so wanted to find a typo in your question and edit it.  Maybe I'll come back in a year.

Comment: Needs an [—](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm), but I fear [Muphry's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry's_law).